# Text field default value overrides user input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm setting some default value for my text fields and those fields are in read only mode. When I pass new values to the those fields and submits the form it saved default value not the new one. I have used PostBack function but it's not working. Here is my code,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (! this.IsPostBack)
       {
           MakeReadControl();
       }
    }


    private void MakeReadControl()
    {
            ((TextBox)this.FindControl("txtMedicalCheckup")).Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            ((TextBox)this.FindControl("txtBosiet")).Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            ((TextBox)this.FindControl("txtLandSurvival")).Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            ((TextBox)this.FindControl("txtDefensiveDriving")).Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            ((DropDownList)this.FindControl("comboDrivingLicense")).SelectedIndex = 1;
            ((TextBox)this.FindControl("txtOtherLicense")).Text = "Not available";
    }
```

However, the drop down list updates the value correctly.

**Update:-**

Instead of Read Only attribute if I use enable attribute then it works fine.

Comment: An Update function can still READ your object, so you need to track your original value, or track which objects have a default value and actively avoid updating those specific columns.

Comment: But when I submit the form why should I worry about default value ? At the end I need to submit the user input.

Comment: sorry, I missed the part where you were submitting new values to your objects. Have you tried turning off the read only option, and while leaving everything else the same, try to do an update?  I'm pretty new to asp.net, but I think it may do that it is simply ignoring your new value because of that.

Comment: Thanks Limey , Indeed if I remove "Readonly" property it saves. But I must use read only property when page loads. This looks strange to me.

Comment: Then leave it as Readonly, but before you change, simply make writables, change the value, then make it read only again.